# Trying to remove Bluetooth, safe to do?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a computer that has 0 Bluetooth support, I wish to remove the options for it so my users don't get confused or frustrated thinking the computer DOES have Bluetooth when in fact it doesn't. I did a grep and found the following packages:

```
bluez
bluez-alsa
bluez-cups
bluez-gstreamer  
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0    
gnome-bluetooth    
libbluetooth3    
libgnome-bluetooth8    
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Are any of these packages of any system importance besides Bluetooth comparability?

If I where to run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove bluez* *bluetooth*
```

Would this be a safe command to run?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

After doing the apt-get commands, I was able to remove everything but "libbluetooth3" and "libgnome-bluetooth8" as they wanted to uninstall other things with them.